# am getting an error on how to use the .max() function. how can i proceed?

Tags: python-3.x

am getting that error?

[image]

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "python", line 5, in `<module>`
>   NameError: name 'maximum' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You have to return `maximum` in your `max()` and then call your defined function in `print` or put `print(maximum)` in `max()` definition and just call defined function.

I would suggest to rename your function.

Answer (score -1):

You def a function, but neither call it or makes it return.